# Partial Fraction Decomposition of quadratic factor

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to break up the following equation into partial fractions:
$$\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2(x-1)^2}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{(x+1)^2}$$

I'm ending up with two equations and four unknowns though:
$$A+C=0 \\ -A + B + C+D = 0$$
(these are the $x$ and constant coefficient variables).

How do I break this up completely?

Comment: There are two more equations, but it's hard to tell how/why you missed them without more details.

Comment: When I put it all together I get: $A(x-1) + B + C(x+1) + D$. I only get equations from grouping constant coefficients and the terms on $x$. Is this the detail you were referring too?

Comment: Not sure how you got that. The numerator should rather be $\,A(x-1)(x+1)^2$ $+B(x+1)^2$ $+C(x+1)(x-1)^2$ $+D(x-1)^2\,$.

Comment: @yoshi what exactly did you do to "put it all together"? You should have ended up with a degree 3 polynomial

Comment: AHH! okay stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{(x+1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{A(x+1)(x^2-1)+B(x+1)^2+C(x-1)(x^2-1)+D(x-1)^2}{(x^2-1)^2}=$$

$$=\frac{A(x^3+x^2-x-1)+B(x^2+2x+1)+C(x^3-x^2-x+1)+D(x^2-2x+1)}{(x^2-1)^2}=$$

that is

- $A+C=0 \implies A=-C$
- $A+B-C+D=0\implies 2A+B+D=0$
- $-A+2B-C-2D=0\implies B=D \implies A=-B$
- $-A+B+C+D=1\implies -2A+2B=1 \implies A=-\frac14$

and then $A=-B=-C=-D=-\frac14$

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint: $\;\dfrac{1}{x^2-1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{x-1}-\dfrac{1}{x+1}\right)\,$, and therefore:

$$
\dfrac{1}{(x^2-1)^2}=\dfrac{1}{4}\left(\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}-\dfrac{2}{x^2-1}\right)=\ldots
$$